# Communicate with a browser with C++ sockets

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, server, http-headers

I challenged myself to code a small frontend framework. For this, I need a small server that takes .js files containing syntaxes similar to what can be found in React and converts them into JavaScript understandable for the browser, I decided to do this in C++ with the sockets but I'm still a long way off...

At first, I try at least to send the contents of the index.html file to the browser and for that no problem : I create an HTTP header which gives the MIME type (Here text/html) and other info and I add the content retrieved in the index.html.

But when I add in the index.html a simple  the browser loads without stopping. If I send a 2nd request with a hard JavaScript content (And the MIME type test/javascript) I see that in the "network" tab of the Chrome inspector the browser has received the content of index.html and not the JavaScript code yet sent hard... I tried all sorts of solutions without success.

Here is the C++ code :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    app app;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a socket (IPv4, TCP)
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create socket. errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::string address = std::string(argv[1]);
    std::string port = std::string(argv[1]);

    if(address.find(":")==std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "Please give a port number" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    address.erase(address.find(":"));
    port.erase(0,port.find(":")+1);

    if(address=="localhost")
        address="127.0.0.1";

    sockaddr_in sockaddr;

    sockaddr. sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address.c_str());//INADDR_ANY;
    sockaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(port.c_str()));
    // htons is necessary to convert a number to
    // network byte order

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to bind to port. errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int connection;

    // Start listening. Hold at most 10 connections in the queue
    if(listen(sockfd, 10) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to listen on socket. errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } // Grab a connection from the queue

    while(1)
    {
        connection = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr, nullptr);

        if(connection < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to grab connection. errno: " << errno << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::string contentHTML=app.readIndexHTML(); //Get content of index.html

        std::ostringstream os;

        os << contentHTML.size();

        std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-length: " + os.str() + "\r\n\r\n" + contentHTML;
        send(connection, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0); //Send HTML content

        response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/javascript\r\nContent-length: 59\r\n\r\ndocument.querySelector(\"#aa\").innerHTML = \"< h1>Hi</h1>\";"; //JS-code
        send(connection, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0); //Send JS code but browser receives again HTML code ...
    }

    close(connection);
    close(sockfd);
}
```

The index.html is very simple :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project Electron</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="aa">Test</h1>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You made a very common mistake of apparently attempting to implement a network program without, first, investing time with a good textbook that teaches network programming. One of the very first things that every textbook that teaches socket programming explains is that if you attempt to `send()`, say, ten thousand bytes, or maybe even a few hundred bytes, the chances of that actually happening are slim to none; the reason for that; and how to actually do that correctly. You will find a complete explanation in your textbook's description of what `send()` returns, and what it means.

Comment: Additionally, the 2nd mistake is implementing an HTTP server without actually implementing HTTP. Setting aside the improper usage of `send()`, the shown code assumes that the browser will request a pipelined connection, and sending the 2nd pipelined response without waiting for the 2nd HTTP request (or even reading the first HTTP request completely). The chances of that working, correctly, are also slim to none. There's a reason why the technical specification of HTTP is almost 200 pages long.